# How to prove that this group is abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a group such that for all $a,b,c\in G$ we have $$ab=ca \implies b=c$$

> How can I show that $G$ is abelian ?

I am kind of stuck in the question

Answer (score 2):

$a(ba) = (ab)a \implies ba = ab;\forall a,b \in G$.